# Apache Airflow can't connect to localhost database

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am using Airflow and Postgres on Docker. I have the following connection where I do a DML command (outside Airflow):

```
 # Constructor method initializing the connection to DB and creating cursor
    def __init__(self, db="projeto-pos", user="postgres", host="localhost", password=my_psswd, port="5433"):
        self.conn = psycopg2.connect(
            database=db, host=host, port=port, password=password, user=user)
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
```

I am using Docker and the Postgres' container is available on localhost:5433. I can perfectly use Pgadmin and do DML commands from Python.

I instantiated the Postgress (`db` ojbect) class and created the following task in a DAG:

```
insert_into = PythonOperator(
        task_id='insert_into',
        python_callable=db.insert_into
    )
```

However, when I open the Airflow UI this messages pops up and I can't run the DAG:

```
Broken DAG: [/opt/airflow/dags/projeto_api.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/functions/db_manipulation.py", line 10, in __init__
    database=db, host=host, port=port, password=password, user=user)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5433 failed: Connection refused
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5433 failed: Cannot assign requested address
    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I am using [this](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/docker-compose.yaml) Dockerfile for Airflow. I also tried in the "connections" section in the Airflow UI, but I got the same message. I know for sure that the connection is up and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname of postgres is "postgres" not "localhost".

this name is defined by the name of the postgres service in the docker-compose.

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
```

also, you can see the connection string in the docker-compose (in bold)

AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@**postgres**/airflow

Comment: You were right! But I have another Dockerfile where I use Metabase and Postgres. In this other Dockerfile I set volumes, networks, etc. Should I delete the Postgres service in the Airflow Dockerfile?

Comment: @LuisFelipe, and your airflow db connection was changed to that docker ? if so, then you don't need the postgres definition in airflow docker cause you created one of yourself.

Comment: No, I haven't changed the airflow db connectipn. Could you please send me a documentation where I can read how to do that? I am new in Airflow. @ozs

Comment: Another problem that I am facing is that if I remove the Postgres service in airflow docker I cannot start all services because some dependes upon Postgres.

Comment: @LuisFelipe, in the docker-compose you have env varaible AIRFLOW__DATABASE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN. you need to changed it according to your new connection. notice that localhost inside airflow its the airflow itself and not the machine. if you are running on same machine the postgres then the hostname is the name of the machine.